# How to change comboBoxColumn display style to combobox programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I know how to do it visually:

Right click the `DataGridView` `->` edit columns `->` set column type to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` `->` set display style to `comboBox`

But I want to do it programmatically.

Here is my code:

```
public void initilizeClientsGridView()
{
     DataGridView clientsGridView = new DataGridView();
     DataGridViewColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

     clientsGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
     clientsGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
     panel1.Controls.Add(clientsGridView);

     clientsGridView.Columns.Add("columns","Estatus");
     clientsGridView.Columns.Add("columns", "Razon social");
     clientsGridView.Columns.Add(comboBoxColumn);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `DataGridViewColumn` to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboBoxColumn.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
```